# why is my set empty when I have added items to it?

Tags: python, set

I have written a function that determines from a non-empty list of duplicate integers, where one it not duplicate, we want to return this non-duplicate integer:

```
nums = [2,2,1]


def singleNumber(nums) -> int:

    int_set = set()
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] not in int_set:
            int_set.add(nums[i])

        if nums[i] in int_set:
            int_set.remove(nums[i])

    return int_set.pop()

print(singleNumber(nums))
```

For some reason I am getting a key error, where it says that the set is empty- why is this? Because when I follow the code, the set should contain [1] when we pop it.

Comment: Inside second `if` you always remove element that you have added in first `if`, hence your set is always empty after each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other people say (in other answers) you have to replace second `if` with `else` for you algorithm to work. But I think your algorithm incorrectly solves your task even after replacement.

For example when you have [2, 2, 2, 1] i.e. when 2 presents odd times then your final set will contain {2, 1}. Actually your code finds numbers that present odd times, not non-duplicates.

One of correct solutions will be when using two sets like below:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5NCsIwEIX3PcVbJhBLYl0JXsELFBdKpxpopyGTLjx9bBvw7/Fg4M03P@GZHhM3OXfUQzzfBzrP442i4nkUfaywSKyBOJwglJQ2pWydfopgeMZKF3iV70sq9pNti1x97TrF@p3SIPTH2G8mUpojQ4nFbhnXdZjCcrsK0XNSPw@3e4NiZ9AYHIovWuf8Ag)

```
def singleNumber(nums):
    s0, s1 = set(), set()
    for n in nums:
        if n in s0:
            s1.add(n)
        else:
            s0.add(n)
    return (s0 - s1).pop()

print(singleNumber([2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4]))
```

Output:

```
1
```

final set will contain {1, 3}.

Answer (score 0):

Your second `if` is always true, because you add the element in the first `if`.

Use `else`.

```
def get_single_number(nums):
    int_set = set()
    for num in nums:
        if num not in int_set:
            int_set.add(num)
        else:
            int_set.remove(num)
    return int_set.pop()

nums = [2,2,1]
print(get_single_number(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

The second if needs to be an else. Currently the first if is true so it gets added to the set. Then the second if is evaluated and is also true since you just added it and it removes from the set.

```
nums = [2,2,1]


def singleNumber(nums):

    int_set = set()
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] not in int_set:
            int_set.add(nums[i])
        elif nums[i] in int_set:
            int_set.remove(nums[i])

    return int_set.pop()

print(singleNumber(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to using

```py
        if nums[i] not in int_set:
            int_set.add(nums[i])

        elif nums[i] in int_set:  # changed
            int_set.remove(nums[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. You should use `elif` or `else` because python will interpret that your code has two `if` statements. Also, the second `if` always evaluates to true.

```
nums = [2,2,1]


def singleNumber(nums):

    int_set = set()
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] not in int_set:
            int_set.add(nums[i])

        elif nums[i] in int_set:
            int_set.remove(nums[i])

    return int_set.pop()

print(singleNumber(nums))
```

Comment: Please remember to provide an explanation why it will work/what did you change.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your program step by step, without the loop to help understanding :\

```py
nums = [2,2,1]


def singleNumber(nums) -> int:

    int_set = set()
    #for i in range(len(nums)):
    i=0
    if nums[i] not in int_set: # There is nothing in int_set
        int_set.add(nums[i]) # we add 2 in int_set

    if nums[i] in int_set: # There is [2] in int_set, so that is true 
        int_set.remove(nums[i])  # We remove 2 from int_set
    # int_set is empty at the end of the second iteration


    # Second iteration
    i=1
    if nums[i] not in int_set: # There is nothing in int_set
        int_set.add(nums[i]) # we add 2 in int_set

    if nums[i] in int_set: # There is [2] in int_set, so that is true 
        int_set.remove(nums[i])  # We remove 2 from int_set
    # int_set is still empty


    # Third iteration
    i=2
    if nums[i] not in int_set: # There is nothing in int_set
        int_set.add(nums[i]) # we add 1 in int_set

    if nums[i] in int_set: # There is [1] in int_set, so that is true 
        int_set.remove(nums[i])  # We remove 1 from int_set
    # int_set is still empty 


    

    return int_set.pop() # There is an error because int_set is empty

print(singleNumber(nums))
```

What you can do to fix that is use an else statement instead of two conditions :\

```py
nums = [2,2,1]


def singleNumber(nums) -> int:

    int_set = set()
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] not in int_set:
            int_set.add(nums[i])
        else:
            int_set.remove(nums[i])

    return int_set.pop()

print(singleNumber(nums))
```

or

```py
nums = [2,2,1]


def singleNumber(nums) -> int:

    int_set = set()
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] not in int_set:
            int_set.add(nums[i])
        elif nums[i] in int_set: # That way we don't recheck if something was already added in the current iteration 
            int_set.remove(nums[i])

    return int_set.pop()

print(singleNumber(nums))
```